# How can I write underset tag properly in the reaction below?

Tags: stacking-symbols, mhchem

I am using mhchem tools for writing chemical reaction in my blog. How should I rewrite the code in the reaction below so that the text `Rust` appears just below the product?

And this is the code I have tried:

```
\ce{Fe^+++ + 2OH^-->\underset{\text{Rust}Fe(OH)3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\ce{Fe+++ + 2OH- -> $\underset{\text{Rust}}{\ce{Fe(OH)3}}$}
```

Comment: @NarayanSharma Please mark this question as answered if you are happy with the answer.